# HTTP requests in a service/provider

Tags: ionic-framework, httprequest

I would like to get all my HTTP requests in a provider, and access it from the different components.
But I'm facing an issue on the return statement.

Please find the code inside db.ts which is my provider:

```
  public getData(endPoint) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/' + endPoint + '?order=id.asc')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {
        var dataRetrieved = [];

        for (var i=0 ; i<data.length; i++) {
          dataRetrieved.push(data[i]);
        }

        return dataRetrieved;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return 'error';
    });
  }
```

And I would like to retrieve data in my component (home.ts) :

```
this.data = db.getData('comments');
```

Where the declaration of this.data is :

```
public data: Array<{
    id,
    title,
    description
  }>;
```

But I have an issue 'Impossible to assign "void" type to type "{ id: any, title: any, description: any }[]"'.

Could you help please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because the function `getData()` has a return type `void` and the variable in which you're holding the response from `getData()` is of type `Array<{id, title, description}>` which is clearly a mismatch. You can do a couple of things here to resolve the issue:

1. Make `data` of type `any` -> `public data: any`.
2. Return `Array<{id, title, description}>` from `getData()` ->  `public getData(): Array<{id, title, description}>`

Comment: Thanks Prasheel, this works.
I tried also, and it works, to return an Observable with a frist return on the request (this.http.get), and another one in the .map that returns res.json() and another one in .catch which is return Observable.throw(error.json()).